# Artificial Smoothing, Diffusion and other effects of numerical Schemes

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question, finite-differences

I am looking for an explanation for the terminology "artificial smoothing" and "artificial diffusion" in the context of numerical schemes.

For instance, consider the upwind scheme where we estimate a derivative of $f$ at $x$ by
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}
$$
where $h>0$ is our mesh-size. This scheme is said to create artificial smoothing. On the other hand, the central discretization
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{h^2}
$$
is said to create artifical diffusion.

How do these concepts explain, for instance, that the upwind discretization is more "stable" in $h$ for problems such as
$$
\begin{cases}
-\epsilon u^{\prime\prime} + u^\prime =1 &\text{in }(0,1)\\
u(0) = u(1) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
when $\epsilon>0$ is small?

Comment: what do you mean by "stable"? respect to what? because the upwind can guarantee maximum principle, which does not create zigzag shape in iterations, does that mean your "stable"?

Comment: @Yimin Yes, thank you for putting it into words.